# Sending POST request to REST endpoint using Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, rest, spring-mvc

I want to submit all fields from registration form and store them in PostgreSQL database. I'm using Spring MVC and jQuery. POST request to /save is working only using Postman. When I click on Register button to submit form it gives me -

> "Request method 'POST' not supported".

Can anybody help me?

**User Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/save", headers="Accept=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.registerUser(user);
    }
}
```

**PageController:**

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login () {
        return "index.html";
    }

}
```

**Model:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name="sex")
    private String sex;

    @Column(name="skype")
    private String skype;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    protected User(){};
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login / Register</title>
<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="login-register-form-section">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#login" data-
 toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#register" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" 
 id="login">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="form-group " >
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                <input type="text" name="login_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username or email" required="required" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></div>
                                <input type="password" name="login_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe">
                            <label for="rememberMe">Remember Me</label>
                            <a href="#" class="pull-right">Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>  
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success btn-custom">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="register">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="form-group" id="sex">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                <select type="text" name="gender" class="form-control">
                                <option>Male</option>
                                <option>Female</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-male"></i></div>
                                <input type="text" name="register_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
                                <input type="email" name="register_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></div>
                                <input type="text" name="register_skype" class="form-control" placeholder="Skype name" required="required" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
                                <input type="password" name="register_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Register" class="btn btn-success btn-custom">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(
function($) {

    $("#submitbtn").click(function(event) {

        var data = {}
        data["sex"] = $("#sex").val();
        data["skype"] = $("#register_username").val();
        data["username"] = $("#register_email").val();
        data["email"] = $("#register_skype").val();
        data["password"] = $("#register_password").val();

        $("#submitbtn").prop("disabled", true);

        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 url: "/save",
                 data: JSON.stringify(data),
                 dataType: 'json',
                 timeout: 600000,
                 success: function (data) {
                     console.log("DONE");
                 },
                 error: function (e) {
                     console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                     display(e);
                 }
        });


    });

});
```

Comment: Change the content type in your controller to contentType: "application/json"

Comment: like this? headers="Accept=application/json"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that I wasnt selecting the dom elements correctly, instead of id="email" I was using name="email".

```
<input type="text" name="register_skype" ...... >
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing input type='submit' can you try using  input type='button'

change the line  `data["username"] = $("#register_email").val(); to  data["userName"] = $("#register_email").val();`

Comment: I think your JSON field names are not matching. In your class you have userName and in jquery you have it as username.

Comment: Doesnt work. It looks like it doesnt see the file with jQuery, because if the function fail it should execute the "error:" block right?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending `application/json` in your ajax call, but in your controller, you say that your endpoint only accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You can change your controller to accept `application/json`:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/save", headers="Accept=application/json")
```

To avoid typos, you could also use the `@RequestMapping`'s `consumes` attribute, and pass it a `MediaType` constant:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/save", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Or you can refactor your ajax call to send the serialized form data.

As [@sparrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012492/2561365) suggests, you may also want to change your button's `type` attribute to `button` in order to avoid the default browser submit behavior. Alternatively, you can call `event.preventDefault();` inside your click handler function to accomplish the same thing, but it doesn't make much sense to use `type="submit"` unless you're actually wanting to use the browser's default submit behavior.

Comment: Did it. Now when I click nothing happens, no error, no message in console.

Comment: I looks like it doesnt see the file with jQuery. I dont know why.

Comment: There is no problem when I try POST request to url: /save using Postman, it successfully store data to DB.